# Is there a way to cleanly write urls in the argument of \href?

Tags: cross-referencing, urls, href

I have a quite long url that I want to include in-text in a document of mine and would like to avoid having it in the middle of my writing. Is there a way to make this into a simple reference to the hyperlink somewhere else? Maybe a referencing command similar to \includegraphics, but that would work for hyperlinks?

I would like to do something like the following

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{reference to url elsewhere in document}{consectetur adipiscing elit}...

rest of document

url reference here or somewhere else
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a bibliography entry or a footnote?

Comment: A bibliography entry might work. My main issue is that long urls clutter the source code and I don't want that if I can help it.

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look at the hyperref package at ctan. One of its nice features is to deal with long urls in print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store url's in commands. If they contain special chars, escape them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\myurla{https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref}
\newcommand\myurlb{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier\#Syntax}
\begin{document}
\href{\myurla}{link to hyperref on ctan}

\href{\myurlb}{link with hash}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh this is actually perfect. I don't know why I didn't think of it! Thank you very much.